# How to answer a phone call programmatically Xamarin | Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm building an app using xamarin android, I'm implementing a feature where I want to answer call programmatically; I have an idea that I need to use `Intent` but how? that's what I don't know.

Any one can suggest me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a broadcast receiver that will manage your incoming call:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter (new [] {"android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"})]
    public class IncomingPhoneCallDetector : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Extras != null)
            {
                string state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);
                if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)
                {
                    string telephone = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);             
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (telephone)) 
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText (context, "Incoming call from " + telephone + ".", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText (context, "Incoming call from unknown number.", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                    }
                    Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaButton);
                    buttonDown.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraKeyEvent, new KeyEvent(KeyEventActions.Up, Keycode.Headsethook));
                    context.SendOrderedBroadcast (buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
                }
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Incoming call answered.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Incoming call ended.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried your code , but it's not working.it receive phone state correctly but it not answer the call , is it any permission required or any restrictions base on android version ? Best regards